# How to overwrite or replace scenario result in Cucumber Extent Report after re-run

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, extentreports

@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/feature", glue = "com.my.test.steps", plugin = {"pretty",
"junit:target/report.xml", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
"json:target/cucumber.json", "rerun:target/filedScenario.txt" }, tags = "@mytest")

Using cucumber extent report. re-run failed scenarios but extent report append all execution of scenarios. i need to replace the scenarios by latest one.

if anyone know the solution, old extent report had setAppend method but in newer version the deprecated.